# Only getting every other value for array in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I'm trying to ready a set of values from a .txt and store them into an array in C. I've got it working but for some reason it's only getting every other value, seemingly only the even-indexed values I guess.

```
for (k=0,total=0; fscanf(lab,"%lf",&y[k]) != EOF && k<=N-1;total++, k++)
    {
        fscanf(lab,"%lf",&y[k]);
        sum += y[k];
        printf("%lf \n",y[k]);
    }
```

That's the loop I'm using to read the input values. I'm very new to this.

Comment: If your new to this you should refactor your code to be more easily read (e.g. don't use an `fscan` call as the loop termination condition. In fact this is really more suited to a while loop than a for loop.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know of any other way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling fscanf twice per iteration. Once in the test fscanf (...) != EOF, then inside the loop.

Comment: Okay, I see. That did it! Thank you very much for your help. I just thought the fscanf in the for statement was used as a condition, I didn't know it was using it to execute.